# MyBatis with Guava multimap

Tags: java, guava, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I want to use [Guava multimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) as a [resultMap](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Result_Maps) with [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/), to return a resultset that has a collection of several one to many entries, but I am not able to figure out the exact syntax for the same. Below is a sample of my table :

```
+----+---------+----------+-------------+
| ID | PART_ID | NAME     | PART_FAMILY |
+----+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 |       1 | bush     |         300 |
|  2 |       1 | a-bush   |         300 |
|  3 |       1 | 300-bush |         300 |
|  4 |       2 | nut      |         301 |
+----+---------+----------+-------------+
```

I want a resultset such that I have a Guava multimap with PART_ID as the key, and NAME and PART_FAMILY as the result.

**Ex :**

```
Index 0 :
    Key : 1 //PART_ID
    Value : [NAME: bush, PART_FAMILY: 300]
Index 1 :
    Key : 1
    Value : [NAME: a-bush, PART_FAMILY: 300]
Index 2 :
    Key : 1
    Value : (NAME: 300-bush, PART_FAMILY: 300)  
Index 3 :
    Key : 2
    Value : (NAME: nut, PART_FAMILY: 301)
```

And below is my query :

```
<resultMap id="partsMap" type="com.google.common.collect.Multimap">
    <id column="PART_ID" property="key" />
    //Not sure what to put here
</resultMap>

<select id="getParts" resultMap="partsMap">
    SELECT 
    PART_ID, NAME, PART_FAMILY
    FROM PART_NAMES
    WHERE ${filter}
    ORDER BY PART_ID
</select>
```

I wanted help with the below points :

1. Can mybatis return the a resultMap in a Guava MultiMap as per what I have described above?
2. If yes, can you please help me with the syntax for the same?
3. If no, then how can I obtain the resultset as mentioned in the example?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try it it can?

Comment: @Eugene , yes, I tried it, and it throws the below exception :
Error querying database. Cause: org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: Error instantiating interface com.google.common.collect.Multimap with invalid types () or values (). Cause: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.google.common.collect.Multimap.<init>()

Comment: ok so apparently mybatis is trying to initialize `Multimap` via a default constructor, which obviously does not exist. Multimaps are populated only at creation time or via a `Builder`, since they are Immutable. I think that your only option here is to create a `Map<Key, List>` and then use some factory methods to create a `MultiMap` out of that.

Comment: `resultMap` requires a constructor. `Multimap` doesn't offer any, nor its various implementations.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire , can I extend the Multimap , provide a constructor, and use this new class instead?

Comment: Yes, of course! You should probably use a `ForwardingMultimap` for that use case. That way you only have to define the following: `public class MyMultimap<K,V> extends ForwardingMultimap<K,V> { private Multimap<K,V> delegate = HashMultimap.create(); public MyMultimap() {} @Override public Multimap<K,V> delegate() { return delegate; } }`. I cant' really help for the mapping, though.